# Mysqld bind-address won't change

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up a remote database but I am encountering an issue I cannot find a solution for. Namely, when I edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and set bind-address to 0.0.0.0, nothing happens after I restart the `mysql` service. I even tried restarting the machine several times during this process.

When I enter into mysql as root and do the `show variables` commands, it still shows `127.0.0.1` on `bind-address`. However, when I do `mysql --help`, it shows `(no default value)` for bind-address variable. I tried `mysql --bind-address=0.0.0.0`, but it requires access. If I do provide it, it just enters mysql shell and does no changes to bind-address.

If I try to`telnet MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS 3306`, it says `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. I consequently check listening services by doing `sudo netstat -ltup` and it says localhost:mysql and *:* for local address and foreign address respectively. Finally, if I do `lsof -Pni :3306` I get `127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)`.

Any idea what is happening? Help is appreciated.

Comment: */etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf* is not the only configuration file which may be loaded - find and check all of them. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: check all the configs and just remove bind-address, don't set it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Is the firewall configured to open port 3306?

Comment: @FlashThunder I will do as you suggest. However, isn't it the same thing? Doesn't removing the bind-address in the config default it to 0.0.0.0? 

EDIT: After restarting the service and machine, nothing has changed from the aforementioned. Additionally and strangely enough, "(no default value)" was corrected back to localhost when I set it back to the machine's IP address, but now after commenting out "bind-address", it reverted back to "(no default value)" after restarting.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for the link and I checked every file; /etc/my.cnf does not exist and /etc/mysql/my.cnf just has "!includedir" on the other two conf files. First !includedir one is just mysql settings which is empty (except for "[mysql]" on the top). Second one has mysqld settings but they don't seem to change any settings for mysqld. Other files than these don't seem to exist.

Additioanlly, I even tried to find more files by going to the root directory and using the "find . -name "my.cnf" -print" command. Each one I checked, no recurrence of "bind-address" or any configurations at all.

Comment: @IgorGreg Yes, with the command "sudo ufw allow mysql". I completely understand the dangers of 0.0.0.0 and a completely open firewall. It will be removed once I manage to log in with the least restrictive conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to kill the process ( `ps -ef | grep mysql` find the pid and then `kill -9 <pid i found>`) and start it again.

For some reason the `service mysqld restart` doesn't do anything but I thought it did - and I kept changing the configuration while the server let me to believe it is restarting ( also the `service mysqld stop` didn't do anything)

Once I manually killed it and started it - the `my.cnf` started to work.
After every command I run `netstat -l` and watched this row:

```
# Changed from:
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

# To:
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Then i was able to connect from outside

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the instruction in MariaDB "[Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/#:%7E:text=with%20%3B%20or%20%5Cg.%0A...-,Finding%20the%20Defaults%20File,address%20left%20as%20the%20later%20%2D%2Dskip%2Dbind%2Daddress%20will%20overwrite%20it,-.)"
but I couldn't find any binding address option, so I've followed the alternate option
"[Alternatively, just add the following lines at the end of your .my.cnf ....](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/#:%7E:text=Alternatively%2C%20just%20add%20the%20following%20lines%20at%20the%20end%20of%20your%20.my.cnf%20(notice%20that%20the%20file%20name%20starts%20with%20a%20dot)%20file%20in%20your%20home%20directory%20or%20alternative%20last%20in%20your%20/etc/my.cnf%20file.)"

```
    [mysqld]
    skip-networking=0
    skip-bind-address
```

but it didn't help, killing the process either.
Finally, by doing `grep -rIH "bind-address"` from the root directory I found the file containing the binding option sets:

```
    etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

Changing there the binding-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 did it.